# Restored wallet from seed, but balance still coming up 0

Tags: wallet-recovery

A while ago my computer crashed resulting in me needing to restore my Monero CLI wallet (which is now running on Helium Hydra 0.11.1, Mac OS Sierra) from my recovery seed. I re-synced the entire blockchain, re-entered the seed to restore my wallet, and allowed the blockchain to refresh from block height 0 as well (since I didn't remember the block height at which the transactions I had made had occurred). However, when this process was completed, my balance still shows up at 0. I'm not sure what I did wrong here and why my balance is not being recognized. I'm hoping I didn't lose my coins because of this. Does anyone have any potential solutions or insight they can provide? Thanks!

Comment: @Matt Sabia: Is your daemon properly fully synced? Also, does the address match the address of your "old" wallet?

Comment: @dEBRUYNE: Yes, my daemon is fully synced, and the address of this new wallet is the same as the old.

Comment: Resolved! I was actually mistaken about my daemon having been fully synced and the coins are now there!

Comment: Good to hear you resolved your issue :) I am going to close this if you don't mind.